# Can not connect to SQL DB: Lost connection to MySQL server at 'handshake: reading inital communication packet', system error: 0uery

Tags: sql, heidisql

I am trying to connect with HeidiSQL to the SQL DB which is running on the remote server to which I connect through the VPN. I am receiving an error message:

> Lost connection to MySQL server at 'handshake: reading inital
> communication packet', system error: 0uery

I can ping host and telnet to it. Any advice where to dig next?